# AMPScript in Subject Line Comes Up Empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an email with some AMPScript in to to populate a section with the contents of a RSS feed. **I wanted the subject line to automatically list the top article in the RSS feed.**

I added the following in the subject line

```
'%%=v(@title)=%%'
```

and when I test send/send preview the email I receive the fifth article from the feed (which is fine) but when the email is sent for real it has no subject.

Comment: Please update your question include the code from the body of your email that sets the `@title` variable.

Comment: `%%[Var @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParse\RSSParse")
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)
If RowCount(@titles) > 5 THEN
SET @rows = 5
ELSE
SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF
IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") ]%% `

Comment: Is the RSSParse content area returning the same XML for every subscriber?

Comment: Yeah same for all. It links to an RSS feed from a news publication

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the AMPScripts read from top to bottom, i.e., the VAR (`%%=v(@title)=%%`) is above the definition and therefore cannot be discerned by the system.

What you'll want to do is throw your AMPScript into a Content Section and then use a `ContentAreaByName` function in the subject line.

Once you have the Content section built, insert this snippet into the Subject Line area:

```
%%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Your Awesome Subject Line")=%%
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is not exactly true. The HTML email itself is fully rendered prior to the subjectline/preheader when an email is sent out by SFMC.  So any variable set inside the email will be fully created prior to being run in subject line. This is salient advice though to keep in mind during the email creation process.

Comment: Quick question, is
    %%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Your Awesome Subject Line")=%%
all I need to put in the subject line or should I also be referencing @title somewhere

Comment: When I tested it, I used:

%%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Your Awesome Subject Line")=%%

In the subject line and then did a "Generate Preview". It worked for me, but try testing this yourself before sending it out to your list.

Comment: What I have now in the content area is this:
    %%[Var *@xml, *@titles, *@title, Set @*xml = ContentAreaByName("my         
    contents\RSSParse\RSSParse") Set *@titles =     
    BuildRowsetFromXML(*@xml,"//item/title",1)  ]%%
    <p>%%=(*@titles)=%%</p>

 Could that be the issue because I get a "unable to generate preview"

Comment: @Shmuel, After some fiddling the code below sends the subject line in test sends but for real sends, it still comes with no subject. Any ideas? 



`%%[Var @xml, @titles, @title, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParse\RSSParse")
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)

If RowCount(@titles) >= 1 THEN
SET @rows = 1
ELSE
SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")]%%
%%=v(@title)=%%
%%[ 
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF]%%`

Comment: I was afraid of this happening. 

So I set out to see what would happen if I try it myself.

It works. I.e., my method. I suggest taking all your AMPScripts and sticking them into the content area so that all you would have to populate the subject line would be the ContentByArea call.